# Function strlen() not return correct length

Tags: php, strlen

I dont know why strlen() doesnt return correct length of string. Actual length is 29 , but strlen() return 41 . Please help.

```
$str = htmlentities('<td bgcolor=#FFFFFF>2-0</td>');
echo strlen($str);
```

Comment: Done. Thank guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your string with the HTML entities escaped is:

```
&lt;td bgcolor=#FFFFFF&gt;2-0&lt;/td&gt;
```

The length of this string is 40 characters (not 41 as you state in your question), which is correctly returned by the call to `strlen()`.

Without escaping the HTML entities, the length is 28 (not 29).

```
echo strlen('<td bgcolor=#FFFFFF>2-0</td>'); // 28
echo strlen(htmlentities('<td bgcolor=#FFFFFF>2-0</td>')); // 40
```

Comment: alright i just got the correct length by using html_entity_decode . anyway thanks for your help ;) nice day my friend.

Comment: @bambostar If someone's answer here helped you solve your question, it's considdered polite to accept the answer by clicking the green checkmark on the left. It's a way of showing your appreciation and it makes sure your question doesn't remain unanswered forever.

Comment: sorry im new at stackoverflow. i just done feedback. thank guys